# Ehcache of spring doesn't work correctly between microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache, microservices

I have a monolithic application.According to microservices appearance and It that needs to adapt with this appearance splited into small APPs.You assume after splinting each Microservice has a model that has one object that is same in all microservices.The following example for clearing.

Into Micro1:

```
Class A {
private Object obj;

//getter and setter
}
```

Into Micro2:

```
Class B {
private Object obj;

//getter and setter
}
```

and `Object obj` has its own repository and service and controller layer.
There is the config of ehcash of spring at save method into service layer of this model. like this:

```
@Transactional
@Override
@Caching(evict = { @CacheEvict(value = "obj", key = "#obj.id" ) })
public Integer save(Object obj) {
    //Code here
}
```

It was working when the application was a monolithic but after spliting because of this `obj` as a dependency is into all Microservices and this method(save method) is repeated into each microservice,the ehcash doesn't work correctly.
How do I do that when each microservice affects the Object obj other microservices aware to.

Answer (score 2):

there are many solution that can help you in this problem , redis have good integration with spring and you can easily use it for sloving your problem , you can read more about it in this [link](http://caseyscarborough.com/blog/2014/12/18/caching-data-in-spring-using-redis/)

also there solutions likes [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com) , it's a datagrid and more than a simple key-value cache.